# iPhone SDK: Transition between views loses animation after a while of using the app

Tags: iphone, uiview, uiviewcontroller, uiviewanimation, uianimation

I have an unusual problem with my views - after a while of using my tabbar based app, I noticed that the sliding transition between views stops and instead the view just changes (no animation at all). I can't understand how or why it's happening as it happens at random - i.e. it doesn't occur on a particular view, it may happen at any stage of using the app.

Has anyone had this problem before and how did you solve it/find the code that was causing the problem?

EDIT:
I think this code (which is used to go a to a view i.e another tab from my home tab) may be causing the problem.

```
self.tabBarController.selectedIndex = 1;


UINavigationController *firstNavController =
(UINavigationController *)[self.tabBarController selectedViewController];

[firstNavController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:NO];
```

Comment: do you have any custom modifications/subclasses made, or does it appear with the default controls? If second: can it be reproduced by creating a new blank project?

Comment: please see my edit, I am using only default controls. I think the code above may have something to do with it. I am using this code to go to a view from my "Home" tab

Comment: This also happens to me with my file manager app. Seems like a bug in UIKit.

Comment: Why do you pop to the root view controller with animated: NO? That will cause a jump without animation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

// Try using below code. Just changed animated NO to animated YES.

self.tabBarController.selectedIndex = 1;

UINavigationController *firstNavController =
(UINavigationController *)[self.tabBarController selectedViewController];

[firstNavController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];